# Object slicing in Java

Tags: java, type-slicing

Can you take a subclass object and somehow convert it to an object of the same type as the parent class and at the same time slicing all the fields that are not part of the parent class?

I know you can do this in C++, but I have no idea how to do it in Java.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'slicing the fields that are not part of the parent class'?  Sounds like a job for the Slap Chop.

Comment: The OP means to create an instance of the parent class which has the sames member variable values as that in a child instance.  All the 'new' child instance variables have been sliced off.

Comment: Object Slicing Reference - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If i understand the question, one technique is to implement a copy constructor in the parent class. You can then call that constructor with any subclass and it'll produce a copy as a parent-class type.

Comment: I suppose you could do this with Reflection right?  Just create a new instance of the parent class, walk the class fields of the parent class and get the values of those fields from the child class and assign them to the new instances fields.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: thanks, I've read it. IMHO sounds like a bug rather then like a c++ feature.

Comment: Please note that the fact this happens in C++ is not a "feature" - it's something you want to avoid.

Comment: @Neil: Yeah, I've heard it called a phenomenon or issue, not a technique one would actually want to use.

Comment: @nicerobot: if the technique exists and has an accepted name and a nice and shiny detailed Wikipedia entry, it is probably that it *has* proven useful in some cases. It would be great if you could tell if Java supports or not object slicing instead of questionning the OP's need.

Comment: @wizardofodds i asked because i have never come across a reason to do that in Java so i'm curious of their use-case. Is curiosity not a valid reason to ask a question any more? Oops! =P BTW, a shiny wiki doesn't imply utility nor accuracy as the wiki claims "it is not possible in Java" yet i provided a means in Java to accomplish the same. Additionally, to me, the wiki implies Object Slicing acts more like a bug, not a feature, so, again, i'm curious why it'd be useful since there's no practical example in the wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Parent {
    private int fieldA;

    Parent(int fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    Parent(Parent object) {
        this.fieldA = object.fieldA;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    private int fieldB;

    Child(int fieldA, int fieldB) {
        super(fieldA);
        this.fieldB = fieldB;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like `Parent parent = new Parent(child);` and you will achieve the desired result, but as others commented this won't be a *conversion* but rather construct an entirely new object.

Comment: Just to take it a step further 

    class myParent<T extends myParent>{
      // myParent fields here
      myParent( T someDescendant ){
        // copy only the fields visible to myParent here
      }
    }

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change the runtime type of an object in Java (though you can assign a reference to and object to a supertype, and cast back to a subtype). You would need to construct a new object of the superclass runtime type.

I would generally recommend that all classes should be abstract or leaf (conceptually `final`, if not actually marked as such for pragmatic reasons).

Comment: Everything abstract or final? That sounds a bit extreme.

Comment: Why would you have all your classes be abstract or leaf?

Comment: I don't abide by that particular mantra, but in practice I find that seems to be the case anyway. As Joshua Bloch says (to paraphrase), "Either plan for extension or forbid it".  All abstract or final classes is the logical extreme of that philosophy.

Comment: `abstract^final` is not supposed to be popular. It's supposed to be good for your code.

Comment: @Tom:  Also Scott Meyers gives the advice: 'Make non-leaf classes abstract.' in *More Effective C++*.

Comment: @miorel: btw, Joshua Bloch said *"final is the new private"* and strongly recommends making *everything* final.  The technique suggested by Tom Hawtin is a good start.  I go even further: 200KLOC here and there isn't a single class that is not final.  Better, there isn't a single abstract class.  Because I don't believe in "code reuse" (I much prefer delegation and multiple inheritance) and because I think that it's even better for the code when you're not relying on implementation details...

Comment: @Jason Nichols: preventing extension of concrete implementations, sure.  But that doesn't prevent you from having a nice adaptable design where you model *everything* using Java interfaces (aka C++ pure abstract classes) even though all of your classes are final.

Comment: @WizardOfOdds IIRC, "final is the new private" refers to fields (which always were `final` where appropriate to me anyway). Non-final fields annoy the hell out of me when I'm auditing mountains of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct analog of slicing in Java, but I'm sure you can simulate this by adding a member function to either the parent or child that will create a new parent instance for you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen type-slicing in Java. And i don't think there's much need of it...

You can anytime do this in Java

```
Object x = new String("hello");
```

Here you will not have all the functions that String class provides

Comment: True, but you will still get the String version of any Object methods which are overridden.

Comment: “Java” is not, and has never been, an acronym.

Comment: But:  You can do something like `Object o=new String("hello");  String s=(String)o;`

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure why you want to do this, but you could have two classes implement the same interface, then reference the objects by the interface.  For example:

> class A implements something...
>   class B implements something...

```
something = new A();    
something = new B();
```

Comment: Why the downvote, this would effectively do what the person was asking.  Have class B extend A.

Comment: Then you could have: 
A a=new A();
B b=new B();

Then you could do something like: 
something s1=a;
something s2=b;

Comment: You could also just do (if B extends A): A tmp=b;